# Blocking Behaviour of GoRoutines in Golang

Tags: function, go, concurrency, goroutine

Given the following pseudo-code:

```
func main() {
  go runFuncOne()
}

func runFuncOne() bool {
  runFuncTwo() 
  return true
}

func runFuncTwo() bool {
  // Do some heavy work
  return true
}
```

Would `runFuncTwo` only be blocking to `runFuncOne` (the calling goroutine) or would `runFuncTwo` also block `main()` as it is not itself running as a goroutine?

My assumption is that `main()` will open a thread within which `runFuncOne()` and `runFuncTwo()` will then operate. Any work performed within `runFuncTwo()` will then only block this instance of `runFuncOne()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

runFuncTwo blocks runFuncOne only, as both are running in a separate Go routine.

Note though that main() will therefore continue and exit, causing the program to exit.  To avoid this and all runFuncTwo to complete, you should use a sync.WaitGroup.

Comment: Brilliant, makes sense - Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Go statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Go_statements)
>
> The function value and parameters are evaluated as usual in the
>   calling goroutine, but unlike with a regular call, program execution
>   does not wait for the invoked function to complete. Instead, the
>   function begins executing independently in a new goroutine. When the
>   function terminates, its goroutine also terminates. If the function
>   has any return values, they are discarded when the function completes.

```
func main() {
  go runFuncOne()
}
```

`main` will invoke `runFuncOne()` as a goroutine and then exit the program immediately, terminating `runFuncOne()` without waiting for it to complete.

```
func runFuncOne() bool {
  runFuncTwo() 
  return true
}

func runFuncTwo() bool {
  // Do some heavy work
  return true
}
```

`runFuncOne()` makes a function call to `runFuncTwo()` so it will wait for `runFuncTwo()` to complete.

Comment: Brilliant, makes sense - Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can also use a channel for synchronization:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var ch chan int = make(chan int)
    go runFuncOne(ch)
    fmt.Println("Waiting..")
    fmt.Println(<-ch)
}

func runFuncOne(ch chan int) {
    runFuncTwo(ch)
    ch <- 1
}

func runFuncTwo(ch chan int) bool {
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("Done working..")
    return true
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/h1S4TSdT0w

Return type of `runFuncOne` won't be of consequence if you are calling it with a go routine.